# PyQt5 class Downloader(QDialog) Error - QDialog is not defined

Tags: python, pyqt5, defined

I'm trying to follow a tutorial from Bo Milanovich to create a simple URL downloader. His works but I get an error in the class line sayibf that QDialog is not defined.

Is this a difference between him using PyQt4 and me using PyQt5?

I'm struggling enough to learn IU and the errors make it harder.

Please help. Here is my code. I'm only using the first few lines of the code as adding the code to this dialog box is causing me headaches as well.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys

import urllib.request


class Downloader(QDialog):



    def__init__(self)
    QDialog.__init__(self)

    layout = QVBoxLayout()

    self.url = QLineEdit()
    self.save_location = QLineEdit()
    self.progress = QProgressBar()
    download = QPushButton("Download")
    browser = PushButton("Browse")

    self.url.setPlaceholderText("URL")
    self.save_location.setPlaceholderText("File save location")

    self.progress.setValue(0)
    self.progress.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)

    layout.addwidget(self.url)
    layout.addwidget(self.save_location)
    layout.addwidget(browse)
    layout.addwidget(self.progress)
    layout.addwidget(download)

    self.setLayout(layout)

    self.setWindowTitle("PyDownloader")
    self.setFocus()

    download.clicked.connect(self.download)
    browse.clicked.connect(self.browse_file)
```

Comment: QDialog is in the QtGui module in PyQt4 but in PyQt5 it's in the QtWidgets module.

Comment: Thanks again Alec. I found an error in the next line but was able to sort that. I looked at the similar question and it doesn't help.